# Deploy Rails App to Heroku That Doesn't Use a Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app that uses Firebase for data storage. I've removed the `require 'rails/all'` and replaced it with:

```
    require "action_controller/railtie"
    require "action_mailer/railtie"
    require "sprockets/railtie"
```

I deleted `database.yml`.

When I push to Heroku, it assumes a Postgresql database:

```
2014-06-23T17:42:04.122887+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::LoadError (Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.):
```

Is there something I didn't do that would discourage Heroku from assuming a default database?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps remove add `db` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be that the Gemfile needed to be altered just to include the parts of Rails I need:

```
# gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'actionpack'
gem 'activesupport'
```

Evidently, Heroku looks at the Gemfile and determines that and ActiveRecord dependency requires a database and ActiveRecord is a dependency by default.